# Android sqlite error code 19 please explain?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
public static final String Create_Database2= "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name2 + "("
                + play20 + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + play1 + " LONG, " 
                + play2 + " LONG, " 
                + play3 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play4 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play5 + " LONG, " 
                + play6 + " TEXT, " 
                + play7 + " TEXT, " 
                + play8 + " TEXT, " 
                + play9 + " TEXT, " 
                + play10 + " TEXT, " 
                + play11 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play12 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play13 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play14 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play15 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play16 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play17 + " TEXT, " 
                + play18 + " INTEGER, " 
                + play19 + " TEXT"
                + ") ";
```

i am creating a table by using above method? and i am inserting the values in this table by using this method;

```
 public void fetchplaylist() throws IOException
          {
                this.open();                  
                ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
                String csvFilename2 = "/mnt/sdcard/playlist.csv";
                CSVReader csvReader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename2));
            String Row[] = null;
                while((Row = csvReader2.readNext()) != null) {
                       st1=Row[0];
                       st2=Row[1];
                       st3=Row[2];
                       st4=Row[3];
                       st5=Row[4];
                       st6=Row[5];
                       st7=Row[6];
                       st8=Row[7];
                       st9=Row[8];
                       st10=Row[9];
                       st11=Row[10];
                       st12=Row[11];
                       st13=Row[12];
                       st14=Row[13];
                       st15=Row[15];
                       st16=Row[16];
                       st17=Row[17];
                       st18=Row[18];
                       st19=Row[19];
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play1,st1);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play2,st2);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play3,st3);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play4,st4);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play5,st5);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play6,st6);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play7,st7);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play8,st8);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play9,st9);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play10,st10);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play11,st11);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play12,st12);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play13,st13);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play14,st14);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play15,st15);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play16,st16);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play17,st17);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play18,st18);
                       values2.put(DatabaseHandler.play19,st19);
                   database.insert(DatabaseHandler.Table_Name2, null, values2); }
```

but i am setting sqlite error code 19 constraints fail in my logcat what am i doing worng here?i am unable to understand this please will someone help me understand this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing space before

```
"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

replace it with:

```
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: after making the changes as you mentioned now i am getting this error

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0, any help please its important for me

Comment: The error indicates that you are accessing an array or collection that has no elements. Please point out the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @PramodYadav: Don't know how the CSVReader works, but the cause of the excepetion might be that you check your array for null but you don't check the size of the array before accessing its elements.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear you ContentValues, or put this line

```
ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
```

inside while loop and give space before `" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"`